# Convertir cadena a array de enteros

Tags: java

Buenas. Tengo un `String` de números binarios tipo "001010100101011111011010101101010000001110101011" en un archivo , que leo mediante el siguiente código:

```
public String muestraContenido(String archivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  String linea ="";
  FileReader fr = null;
  int[] binaryValue = new int [257];
  BufferedReader br = null;
    try {


     // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para poder
     // hacer una lectura comoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
     File archivo1 = new File ("cadenaAleatoria.txt");
     fr = new FileReader (archivo);
     br = new BufferedReader(fr);
     String caracter="";
     //int[] cadena=new int[257];


     // Lectura del fichero

     //int i=0;
     while((caracter = br.readLine())!=null){
           // caracter=br.read();
            //binaryValue[i]=caracter;

        linea=caracter + br.readLine();


     br.close();

  }
  }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
     // En el finally cerramos el fichero, para asegurarnos
     // que se cierra tanto si todo va bien como si salta 
     // una excepcion.
     try{                    
        if( null != fr ){   
           fr.close();     
        }                  
     }catch (Exception e2){ 
        e2.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
  // mostrar(linea);

     return linea;

}
```

Bien, lo que quiero hacer es pasar este `String` que acabo de leer , a un array de `int[]`. Mi idea es convertir este `String` en un `int` y posteriormente en un `int[]`. ¿Esto seria posible ? ¿Alguna alternativa mejor que esta?

Comment: ¿Necesitas el número leido en binario o lo vas a usar como decimal?¿necesitas guardar en el arreglo un digito por elemento del arreglo?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te envio un codigo para resolver la conversion:

```
public int[] conversor(String texto){
  texto = "001010100101011111011010101101010000001110101011";
  int digital[] = new int[texto.length()]; // estableciendo capacidad del arreglo con la longitud del texto
  int indice = 0;

  for(char valor : texto.toCharArray()){ // recorriendo caracteres del texto
      digital[indice] = Integer.valueOf(valor) - 48; // convirtiendo el caracter en numero respetando la tabla ASCII
      indice++;
  }

  //mostrando resultados
  for(int x : digital){
      System.out.println("valor: "+x);
  }

   return digital;
  }
```

y este otro código de sugerencia para leer mas eficientemente un archivo texto plano

```
public void cargarArchivo(String direccion){
   List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Path ruta = Paths.get(direccion);
        //Stream<String> flujoStrings = Files.lines(ruta);
        Stream<String> flujoFormateado = Files.lines(ruta, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // cargando el archivo plano
        flujoFormateado.forEach(lineas::add); // almacenando todos los elementos para su analisis

        System.out.println("lineas guardadas: "+lineas.size());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Archivos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizá esto te funcionaría:

```
public int[] parse(String num){
    int[] nums = new int[num.length()];
    for(int i=0; i<num.length(); i++){
        nums[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo rápido sería:

```
String cadena = "001010100101011111011010101101010000001110101011";
char[] cadenaSeparada = cadena.toCharArray();//Conviertes la cadena en arreglo de tipo char
int[] enEnteros = new int[cadenaSeparada.length];//Creas una de entero con la misma longitud
    for (int i = 0; i < cadenaSeparada.length; i++) {
        enEnteros[i] = Character.getNumericValue(cadenaSeparada[i]);//Conviertes el char en int
    }
```